# How do I memoize this recurrence relation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I am solving [Maximum Subarray Sum with One Deletion](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-subarray-sum-with-one-deletion/) on LeetCode:

> Given an array of integers, return the maximum sum for a non-empty subarray (contiguous elements) with at most one element deletion. For input `arr = [1,-2,0,3]`, output should be `4`.

I came up with a recursive solution as below:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int helper(vector<int>& n, vector<int>& cache, int startIndex) {
        if(startIndex>=n.size()) return INT_MIN;
        if(cache[startIndex]!=-1) return cache[startIndex];
        
        int allInclusiveSum=0, sumWithOneDel=0, lowestVal=INT_MAX, maxVal=INT_MIN;
        for(int i=startIndex; i<n.size(); i++) {
            allInclusiveSum+=n[i];
            maxVal=max(maxVal, allInclusiveSum);
            if(i!=startIndex) {
                lowestVal=min(lowestVal, n[i]);
                sumWithOneDel=allInclusiveSum-lowestVal;
                maxVal=max(maxVal, sumWithOneDel);
            }
        }
        
        maxVal=max(maxVal, helper(n, cache, startIndex+1));
        
        return cache[startIndex]=maxVal;
    }
    
    int maximumSum(vector<int>& arr) {
        int i=0, first=arr[0];
        for(i=1; i<arr.size(); i++)
            if(arr[i]!=first) break;
        if(i==arr.size()) return first;
        
        vector<int> cache(arr.size(), -1);
        return helper(arr, cache, 0);
    }
};
```

Unfortunately, this TLEs.  Since I call recursively with `startIndex+1`, I don't really think I am encountering overlapping sub-problems.

Is there a way I could memoize my solution?  If no, why?

Comment: Hmm, 26 views and no comment makes me feel I have missed something/my question is incorrect.  Could someone please point out, so that I could edit it?  Thanks!

Comment: Here is view 27 ;-). Thing is, understanding your (or any) algorithm would take too long for me now, let alone understanding the subtle differences to another one ;-).

Comment: There's an awful lot of code here and no real guidance on where to start looking for the problem. When I hear "memoize" I immediately think "Why not use a `std::map` to cache?" and yet I don't see one, so...

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Oh, just to clarify, I am not asking for a comparison per se.  All I am trying to say is our we have similar DP states, but I am unable to cache my algo, whereas the other author could.  Why so?

Comment: @tadman, I am almost doing that - using a vector (named `dp`) for caching, instead of a `std::map`.  As for guidance, could you please say what you are looking for?  I would be more than happy to add it!

Comment: The problem with "My code is slow please help!!" type questions is we don't even know where to start. This could be a two second fix, or a three day excursion. I think people are really hesitant to commit to solving it because there's no obvious spot where the problem exists. If you want to get to the bottom of the performance issue, strap this into a profiler and find out where the hot spots are.

Comment: It also doesn't help that you name your variables things like `dp` or `n` which are devoid of meaning, at least to us. Do try and tidy that up before posting, a name like `cache` would go a long way towards explaining.

Comment: @tadman, done.  I have also reduced the scope of my question.

Comment: Since you're looking for comments: what the heck is the first `for` loop doing in `maximumSum`? I see no reason for that loop to exist.

Comment: @user3386109 Otherwise it breaks on inputs like `[-1,-1,-1,-1]`. :)

Comment: Improved, but this still isn't complete enough that we could compile it and test it ourselves. As some advice, instead of focusing on this algorithm, experiment with another approach based around memoizing. Tip: Instead of a `vector` filled with "dummy" -1 values, use `std::unordered_map` which either has an entry, or doesn't.

Comment: @tadman, yes, I can try that; but my real question is - _am I encountering overlapping sub-problems in the first place?_?  And if no, why?

Comment: Why not put in some counters to see how often you compute a given value? How many total operations does this code perform? Where could you identify and reduce duplicated processing?

Comment: @P.K. But with that loop, it breaks on inputs like `[1,1,1]` where it will return 1 instead of 3. A better test would be to check if all the array elements are negative, and if so return the max element.

Comment: @user3386109, ah, good point.  I missed that!  Thank you.

Comment: Pretty sure that the code never uses the cache. To prove or disprove that, simply put a `cout << "using cache" << endl;` before the `return cache[startIndex];`

Comment: @user3386109, yep, I just noticed that the same way.  But now I wonder how I should ensure that the cache _is_ used.

Comment: The code is using a combination of recursion and iteration. Notice that the other author's code is strictly recursive. Also, the DP table in the other author's code is a 2D table, indexed as `memo[start][canDelete]`. I think by the time your code is fixed, we would just end up with a copy of the other author's code.

Comment: @user3386109, so I guess my mistake was that I was using a combination of recursion and iteration, which is why I could not effective cache it.  (It was just brute-force in essence).  Thank you, that helps! :)

Comment: @user3386109, if you write it as an 'answer', I would be more than happy to accept it.

Comment: I'm inclined to just let this one go. You can always self-answer :)

Answer (score 0):

With dynamic programming, we would just define a `std::vector` with N rows and two columns, then run through our `arr` in one pass, and use `std::max` to find `max_sum`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


class Solution {
public:
    static inline int maximumSum(const std::vector<int> &arr) {
        int length = arr.size();
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> dynamic_sums(length, std::vector<int>(2, 0));
        dynamic_sums[0][0] = arr[0];
        int max_sum = arr[0];

        for (unsigned int row = 1; row < length; row++) {
            dynamic_sums[row][0] = std::max(arr[row], dynamic_sums[row - 1][0] + arr[row]);
            dynamic_sums[row][1] = std::max(arr[row], std::max(dynamic_sums[row - 1][1] + arr[row], dynamic_sums[row - 1][0]));
            max_sum = std::max(max_sum, std::max(dynamic_sums[row][0], dynamic_sums[row][1]));
        }

        return max_sum;
    }
};
```

It's similarly O(N) time and O(N) memory.

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-subarray-sum-with-one-deletion/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.